# Can't get in the getJSON function()

Tags: php, javascript, json, getjson

I have getJSON code like this:

```
$('#selected_article').change(function(){
    $.getJSON('<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>', {
        ajax: 'ajax_article_partlist' ,
        parent_article: $('#selected_article').val()
    },

    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
 });
```

I can't get the `function(data)`. The `console.log` won't trigger an alert. On the PHP side I get stuff that I need; I can see it in the `error_log`, and I tried with `print` and also `echo`.

Comment: What does the browser console say?

Comment: nothing, i mean i can see the even and the request, but i wont get in the function.

Comment: When debugging JavaScript, it's a good idea to inspect the actual JavaScript source code as it runs on the browser, rather than just the PHP source code you use to generate it. You also need to use your browser tools, esp. the JavaScript console and the network activity panel.

Comment: In developer tools, see network tab. Once you run your ajax request - it should appear there. You can view what is returned and, if question will remain, show it to us. Looks like your response is not a valid JSON and that is why success calback is not called.

Comment: Have you included the jQuery src?

Comment: found the error, forgot to make an exit, after the ajax request in php and in the answer was the full code of the site. @FAngel you may want to submit an answer so i can accept. Thx

Comment: It's me or $.getJSON('<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>' is SELF referencing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In developer tools, see network tab. Once you run your ajax request - it should appear there. You can view what is returned. Looks like your response is not a valid JSON and that is why success calback is not called.